# Measuring peak voltages on two resistors in series using an oscilloscope

Tags: voltage, resistors, oscilloscope, short-circuit, series

A circuit consisting of a function generator that produces a sinusoidal voltage, and two resistors R1 and R2 connected in series is set up according to the image. An oscilloscope is used to measure 3 quantities.

1. The peak voltage over R1 on channel 1 of the oscilloscope.
2. Then the connection from step 1 above is changed to measure the peak voltage over R2.
3. Both peak voltages are measured simultaneously by using both channels of the oscilloscope.

Step 3 results in that the peak voltage over R2 becomes 0 V, it is short circuited.

Why is the peak voltage over R2 short circuited?

[image]

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. This reads as a homework question - is it?

Comment: No i phrased it in such a way to make it more understandable. This is me self studying older material.

Comment: If it's not a homework question, I wouldn't phrase it like one. As shown, it reads like a homework question and there's no effort shown to solve it, no workings on what you've reasoned for yourself already.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is the peak voltage over R2 short circuited?

Because the reference (ground) clip of each probe is shorted internally to the scope's ground:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOnjcn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see from the simplified the schematic above, the reference clips of the probes short the R2 to ground, hence you read 0V.

Answer (score 0):

Each oscilloscope probe has two connections: the point and the clip.  The clips are connected together inside the oscilloscope.

When you connect a clip and a point to one resistor, that's OK.  When you connect a clip and a point to one junction in the circuit, you have shorted the point to ground - even when it is the point of one probe and the clip of the other probe.